# Auto Rotate in Chrome Mobile Apps

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use [Chrome Mobile Apps](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps)

I can't hello world to auto-rotate on either Android 4.4 or iOS if I build with the cca tool.

However the [Chrome App Developer Tool](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/chrome-app-developer-tool/) auto rotates without issue.

Comment: The cordova (not cca) sample app auto-rotates without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Fix by adding: `androidTheme: '@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar'` to `www/manifest.json`

Long answer:
cca has a pre-prepare.js file that it runs after prepare.  If you don't specify an `androidTheme` in `www/manifest.json` then it defaults to `Theme.Translucent`, which somehow causes auto-rotation to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome App Developer Tool isn't actually a `cca` app -- it's a Cordova app, which might make a difference.

I've just compiled and run a basic 'Hello, Mobile' app, and it autorotates fine on Android (This is on Android L; I'll have to wait until the morning to get a 4.4 device)

You can check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file (in `<your project>/platforms/android/`) to see if there is anything relating to `screenOrientation` -- I don't think that mobile Chrome apps should be setting that attribute, but it's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: I created a cca app to test... oddly, it rotates correctly when launched from the command line, but when I start it from the launcher on the phone, it does not.